# SQL Geography River Removal

Tags: polygon, reduce, sqlgeography

How do you remove the 'holes'/linestrings/.etc from a GeographyCollection?  Secondary, how do you join MPolygons that don't intersect into one polygon?

We have a roll up of zipcodes to a geographic map, but we have holes in the shape.  Researched this and that, but I have not found a good way to remove the inner holes.

ConvexHull creates a funky shape that is not really what we want either.  The goal is to have the region 'fit' close together so they are human-viewable on a map.

.Reduce helps, but it does not remove everything.  I really just want the outer envelope with minute (small) ConvexHull occurring only if there are 2 polygons next to each other.

Thoughts?  Redirects?